# Ajax load dosen´t work

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i´m new to tablesorter so i don´t have many experience in that.
My question is simple, i want to load datas with ajax in my table- but i don´t know how should i do that.
I have this code (ajaxServlet) for now:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int row=0;
    JSONArray back = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try{
        Class.forName("com.jdbc.mysql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost/expenses","***","****");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("Select * from expenses");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();


        while(rs.next())
            {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                array.add(rs.getString("UID"));
                array.add(rs.getString("Last Name");
                array.add(rs.getString("First Name"));

                back.add(array);
                row++;
            }

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        obj.put("size", row); // Here  is located the problem i think...what must i return from here?
        obj.put("example", back);
        out.println(obj);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On the HTML side the code is exactly the same as here in the [documentaion](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html)

Just the `ajaxUrl` looks like this:

```
ajaxUrl : "ajaxServlet?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}",
```

So can you please tell me, what must i change or do, that this is working.

Many thanks

Comment: Please post HTML side code it is likely that error is there.

Comment: Ok now my code looks like this, i´v taking some pictures of them: http://img4web.com/g/UM8  In my debugg mode(firefox) i can see that my response from the server is correctly. Also the headers are shown correctly. No error code. But my table is still empty.

Comment: EDIT: My response looks so: "rows" : [{
    "0": 1,
    "1": "Kabul",
    "2": "Kabol",

  }, {
    "0": 2,
    "1": "Qandahar",
    "2": "Al-Sasihm",
  
  }, {
    ...
  }, {
    "0": 25,
    "1": "Peter",
    "2": "South",
   
  }]   "headers" : [
    "UID", "Last Name", "First Name"
  ],  "total_rows": 100,

Comment: Now my table gets the rows fine. I have forget to delete  an extra ':' at the server response. But now my Problem is, that my table shows all rows on just one site(100) the pager not working and the 'rows per page' - setup also not working.

Comment: The pager should be used to interact with your database, if you want to load in all rows of your table, don't use the pager ajax, use the [build table widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-build-table.html#setup__object_json_file_via_ajax), then use the pager to page through the rows (without ajax) that exist in your table.